# Cannot access Javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I've object like this:

```
Object {mime: "image/png", ts: 1372704010, read: 1, write: 1, size: 452343…}
baseUrl: "http://davosovo/images/"
date: "1 Jul 2013 20:40"
dim: "960x400"
hash: "l1_YXBwc1xtb2plLXR2b3JiYS5wbmc"
height: "400"
mime: "image/png"
name: "moje-tvorba.png"
path: "images\apps\moje-tvorba.png"
phash: "l1_YXBwcw"
read: 1
size: 452343
tmb: "http://davosovo/images/.tmb/l1_YXBwc1xtb2plLXR2b3JiYS5wbmc1372704010.png"
ts: 1372704010
url: "http://davosovo/images/apps/moje-tvorba.png"
width: "960"
write: 1
```

And I want the `path` property. But it writes me `undefined` I've tried loop over it like this:

```
for (var key in file) {
console.log(key + ':' + file[key]);
}
```

And it gaves me this:

```
mime:image/png
ts:1372704010
read:1
write:1
size:452343
hash:l1_YXBwc1xtb2plLXR2b3JiYS5wbmc
name:moje-tvorba.png
phash:l1_YXBwcw
date:1 Jul 2013 20:40
tmb:l1_YXBwc1xtb2plLXR2b3JiYS5wbmc1372704010.png
```

Whats wrong?

```
var elfinder = function(callback) {
            jQuery('<div />').dialogelfinder({
                url : '<?= SystemInfo::getDomainUrl() ?>/modules/elrte/php/connector.php',
                lang : '<?= $lang ?>',
                allowShortcuts : false,
                handlers : {
                    select : function (event, elfinderInstance) {
                        var selected = event.data.selected;

                        if (selected.length) {
                            var file = elfinderInstance.file(selected[0]);
                            console.log(file);
                            for (var key in file) {
                                console.log(key + ':' + file[key]);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dblclick: function(event, elfinderInstance) {

                    }
                },
                getFileCallback: callback // pass callback to file manager
            });
        }
```

Comment: It seems you're iterating the properties of the `file` object, but the data you want is on a parent object.

Comment: How can I access them?

Comment: I don't know, where are you storing that object? Can you show more context? I'm saying this based on the first line of the data you posted; it ends with a `}`, meaning that object ends there. What is below must be another object.

Comment: I'm using elFinder. And catching that in select handler. It should be something like that: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-Server-API-2.0#information-about-filedirectory I'd like to show dialog with link to file on double click. But dblclick event is not giving these informations so I decided to save them first in select event.

Comment: Okay, but where did you grab the data you pasted at the top of the question?

Comment: I've just added it into question.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. If you say `file.path` is undefined, I don't know what's going on.